# Sending structs with ZeroMQ and ProtocolBuffers

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I'm writing a program that's supposed to send C structures via ZeroMQ.
Therefore I'm using Google's ProtocolBuffers to serialize the structs.

I do now have the problem that my subscriber side is not receiving anything.
The Publisher prints out "Message successfully sent" so I think the Error occurs on the Subscribers side.

Publisher:

```
int main (void)
{
    Message protomsg = MESSAGE__INIT;
        void *buf;
    unsigned len;

        void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
        void *subscriber = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    zmq_bind(subscriber, "ipc://my.sock");

        //Initialising protomsg (not so important)

        //sending message

        len = message__get_packed_size(&protomsg);
    buf = malloc(len);
    message__pack(&protomsg, buf);

    zmq_msg_t output;
    zmq_msg_init_size(&output, len);
    zmq_msg_init_data(&output, buf, len, NULL, NULL);
    if(zmq_msg_send(&output, subscriber, 0) == -1)
        perror("Error sending message \n");
    else
        printf("Message successfully sent \n");
    zmq_msg_close(&output);
        free(buf);

        zmq_close (subscriber);
        zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
        return 0;
}
```

Subscriber:

```
    int main (void){
        Message *protomsg;
            void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
            void *publisher = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_SUB);
            zmq_connect(publisher, "ipc://my.sock");
            zmq_setsockopt(publisher, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);

            // Read packed message from ZMQ.
        zmq_msg_t msg;
        zmq_msg_init(&msg);
        if(zmq_msg_recv(&msg, publisher, 0) == -1)
            perror("Error receiving message \n");
        else
            printf("Message received");
        memcpy((void *)protomsg, zmq_msg_data(&msg), zmq_msg_size(&msg));

            // Unpack the message using protobuf-c.
        protomsg = message__unpack(NULL, zmq_msg_size(&msg), (void *)&data);   
        if (protomsg == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error unpacking incoming message\n");
            exit(1);
        }

            printf("Address: %u, Type: %u, Information[0]: %u, Information[1]: %u \n", protomsg->address-48, protomsg->frametype, protomsg->information[0], protomsg->information[1]);
        zmq_msg_close (&msg);

        // Free the unpacked message
        message__free_unpacked(protomsg, NULL);

            //close context,socket..
}
```

Comment: There is pretty much no time that the subscriber can connect to the publisher: sockets are non-blocking.

Comment: yes they are. I already ran this code sending strings and not serialized structs, and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Have you followed this? http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Missing-Message-Problem-Solver

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if anyone still cares about this, but here goes...  I agree with @Steve-o that this is a timing issue, although I think the problem is that you are closing the publisher socket too soon.

Your publisher code publishes the message then immediately closes the socket and terminates the context.  So the message exists in the publisher for milliseconds and then is gone forever.

If you run the publisher first, it does it's thing, exits and the message is gone. When you start the subscriber it attempts to connect to an IPC socket that is no longer there.  ZeroMQ allows this and the subscriber will block until there is an IPC socket to connect to.

I have not reviewed the ZeroMQ IPC source code, but I suspect that, under the covers, subscriber is periodically attempting to connect to the publisher socket.  Now if you run the publisher again, it might work but you have a serious race condition.  If you start the publisher at the exact instant the ZeroMQ worker was attempting to retry, the connect might happen and you might even get your message before the publisher destroys everything.

I am pretty sure the problem has nothing to do with structs and protobuf.  From the ZeroMQ point of view you are just sending bytes.  There is no difference.  If your test cases for ZeroMQ strings were truly identical with the test cases for ZeroMQ structs - then perhaps the code change added or removed a few nano-seconds that was able to break the race condition the wrong way.

Specific suggestions:

- rename the socket in publisher to be "publisher" instead of subscriber (copy/paste error)
- add a sleep for 30 seconds just before zmq_close (publisher);
- hopefully this will fix the problem for your test code
- if this does not fix it, consider switching to tcp transport and use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to diagnose what is really going on.